# ARC CCSprite memory leak

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, automatic-ref-counting, ccsprite

I have following code

```
__weak CCSprite *paddleSprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"paddle.png"];
```

Instruments is detecting memory leaks and is telling me that I have memory leak on this line.

Does anybody knows something about this. Isn't CCSprite an autorelease object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve this problem. The problem was actually in Box2d. For b2BodyDef I was having this:

```
paddleBodyDef.userData = (__bridge_retained void*)paddleSprite;
```

But this was incorrect (in my case). Correct is this

```
paddleBodyDef.userData = (__bridge void*)paddleSprite;
```

Also in dealloc method I put

```
paddleBodyDef.userData = NULL;
```

Comment: what is the type of `paddleSprite` and `userData`? Is the above code under ARC? I think you might be under-retaining `userData` here... (And maybe your leak instead was due to a retain cycle)

Comment: This is dangerous too because you declare the sprite as weak. If at any time the box2d userdata is the only reference to the sprite, the sprite deallocates and the userdata pointer becomes garbage. Your bridge retained cast was correct, you simply forgot to bridge_transfer cast userdata to -1 the retain count before setting userdata to null.